# App crashes after upgrading dependencies to latest version in android

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, google-play-services, android-multidex

I am getting following error after upgrading my project to the latest dependencies

> Didn't find class  "com.google.android.gms.common.util.zzq" on 
>         path: DexPathList[[zip
>        file "/system/framework/org.apache.http.legacy.boot.jar", 
>        zip file "/data/app/com.example.example-jBf5YcFyN-t4Cm8erTCBwQ==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.example.example-jBf5YcFyN-t4Cm8erTCBwQ==/lib/x86,
>        /system/lib]]"

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.example"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        // Enabling multidex support.
        multiDexEnabled true

        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            shrinkResources true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    dataBinding {
        enabled true
    }
//    buildToolsVersion '28.0.3'

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:customtabs:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1.1'

    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'

    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
    implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.5'
    implementation 'org.jsoup:jsoup:1.10.3'

    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:16.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:16.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:16.0.0'

    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.3.4'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.5'
    implementation 'com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.9.6'

    implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.32.0'
    implementation 'com.intuit.sdp:sdp-android:1.0.5'
    /*map place autosuggest*/
    //for calendar class
    implementation 'joda-time:joda-time:2.9.9'
    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.2.0'
    //QB dependecies
    implementation 'com.quickblox:quickblox-android-sdk-core:3.8.1'
    implementation('com.quickblox:quickblox-android-sdk-chat:3.8.0') {
        transitive = true
    }
    implementation 'com.quickblox:chat-message-adapter:2.0'
    implementation 'com.quickblox:quickblox-android-sdk-content:3.8.0'
    implementation 'com.timehop.stickyheadersrecyclerview:library:0.4.2@aar'
    implementation 'com.github.orangegangsters:swipy:1.2.3@aar'
    implementation project(':sample-core')

//    implementation 'com.jwang123.flagkit:flagkit:1.0'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

//GoogleServicesPlugin.config.disableVersionCheck = true
```

Can anyone guide me how to solve this issue.
I have been searching stackoverflow from last two days for the solution of this issue. Please help.

Comment: which library can you use ??

Comment: I'm guessing there is some inconsistency between version numbers. Share your build.gradle file

Comment: This is because of different versions of same library in your project. Check for warnings in build.gradle, it helps alot in these cases.

Comment: @ZUNJAE please check i have added the gradle file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Ensure that your top-level build.gradle contains a reference to the google() repo or to maven { url "https://maven.google.com" }.
```

remove this from your build.gradle file and sync again

```
 apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: This is required for using crashlytics...removing this is giving compile time issue

Comment: Please check this document for crashlytics. No need to use apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services. https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/get-started#android

Comment: ok done..finally resolved...although need to change few things as per my project requirement.

Comment: i compulsory require google play service plugin for using implementation 'com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.9.6' else it is giving me the error like " Crashlytics found an invalid API key: null. 
Check the Crashlytics plugin to make sure that the application has been added successfully! 
Contact support@fabric.io for assistance." Can you help with this - @Sultan Mahmud

Comment: @divaPrajapati09 what are the changes you did to resolve this issue?